# bash shell: recursively search folder and subfolders for files from list

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

Until now when I want to gather files from a list I have been using a list that contains full paths and using:

```
cat pathlist.txt | xargs -I % cp % folder
```

However, I would like be able to recursively search through a folder and it's subfolders and copy all files that are in a plain text list of just filenames (not full paths).

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: USe the find command.

Comment: Where will you like the find the folders from? current directory and where to copy the files to? Provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
find folder_to_search -type f | grep -f pattern_file | xargs -I % cp % folder
```

Comment: You seem to have a problem in the `xargs cp`, copy/paste error?

Comment: perfect! I appreciate everyone's help and, no offense to everyone else, but Michael's answer immediately made the most sense to me....and more importantly immediately worked.

Comment: hold up there is a problem. I need it to only grab files that are exact matches and if not to skip them. Right now if I have a file named 123456.tif in the list and there is no matching file in the folder, it is grabbing 23456.tif instead.  How can i fix this?

Comment: A better regex would fix that. `grep -w` is enough to fix this particular problem but there could be peskier ones you can't fix so easily, like `1-234` matching on `234` even with `-w`.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, a typo.

Comment: I just add the w to the f on grep, right? (-fw). When i run that I get a "no such file or directory error". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @AndrewHall No, you don't. The option `-f` expects an argument, namely the file to open. If you write `-fw`, `grep` will try to open a file called `w`, which presumably does not exist.

Comment: can someone tweak Michael's original example to illustrate how I am to incorporate a grep -w? Everything I try keeps giving me the "no such file" error.

Comment: @AndrewHall Well, obviously, you write `-wf`, or `-w -f`, or even `-f pattern_file -w`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of file names contains bare file names, as would be suitable for passing as an argument to `find -name`, you can do just that.

```
sed 's/^/-name /;1!s/^/-o /' pathlist.txt |
xargs -I % find folders to search -type f \( % \) -exec cp -t folder \+
```

If your `cp` doesn't support the `-t` option for specifying the destination folder before the sources, or your `find` doesn't support `-exec ... \+` you will need to adapt this.

Just to explain what's going on here, the input

```
test.txt
radish.avi
:
```

is being interpolated into

```
find folders to search -type f \( -name test.txt -o -name radish.avi \
    -o name : \) -exec cp -t folder \+
```

Comment: Nice :D. This would handle a file named `-name` too.

Comment: this solution didn't work for me because i was getting a permission denied error. the -exec I'm guessing?

Comment: Sounds more like `cp` could not access one or more of the files you found. Hard to tell without the exact error message. Try with `echo` before `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find command.

```
while read line
do
find /path/to/search/for -type f -name "$line" -exec cp -R {} /path/to/copy/to \;
done <plain_text_file_containing_file_names
```

**Assumption:**

The files in the list have standard names without, say newlines or special characters in them.

**Note:**

If the files in the list have non-standard filenames, tt will be different ballgame. For more information see [find manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and look for `-print0`. In short you should be operating with null terminated strings then.